# how do I create a skin for a ValidatorCalloutExtender in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, validation

Based on advice at the foot of this article

http://forums.asp.net/t/1436066.aspx/1

I presume that I ought to be able to create a skin for the AJAX control ValidatorCalloutExtender in ASP.NET. However, when I attempt to do so, my ASPX page warns me

```
Element 'cc1:ValidatorCalloutExtender' is missing required attribute 'runat'.
```

runat="server" is defined in the skin, so it looks like the skin is not being applied. My skin file is

```
~/App_Themes/DM_standard/ValidatorCalloutExtender.skin
```

I have another skin in the same theme/folder, for GridViews, which works fine.

In web.config under system.web I have

```
pages theme="DM_standard"
```

and in the ASPX page itself in the head section I have

link href="/App_Themes/DM_standard/GridView.skin"
link href="/App_Themes/DM_standard/ValidatorCalloutExtender.skin"

The content of ~/App_Themes/DM_standard/ValidatorCalloutExtender.skin is

```
%@ Register 
    Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" 
    Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" 
    TagPrefix="cc1" %

cc1:ValidatorCalloutExtender runat="server" Enabled="True"  
HighlightCssClass="validatorCalloutHighlight"
```

The same <%@ Register .. directive appears at the top of my ASPX page. I've removed all angle brackets in the examples above as I don't know how to stop them being interpreted as HTML.

Should this work, and if so, what do I need to do?